# How to create the database in DataTable Generator

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm using https://editor.datatables.net/generator/ to create a template for a database to integrate it on my site, I've filled all the fields, downloaded the template, put the files on the sever, but in the end, when I set the config.php file with the name of the db it gives me an error.

table.myTable.sql

```
-- 
-- Editor SQL for DB table myTable
-- Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
-- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
    `a` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `b` varchar(255),
    `c` varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);
```

table.myTable.php

```
<?php

/*
* Editor server script for DB table myTable
* Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
*/

// DataTables PHP library and database connection 
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
DataTables\Editor,
DataTables\Editor\Field,
DataTables\Editor\Format,
DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
DataTables\Editor\Options,
DataTables\Editor\Upload,
DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// The following statement can be removed after the first run (i.e. the 
database
// table has been created). It is a good idea to do this to help improve
// performance.
$db->sql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`a` varchar(255),
`b` varchar(255),
`c` numeric(9,2),
);" );

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'myTable', 'id' )
->fields(
    Field::inst( 'a' )
        ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'b' )
        ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'c' )
)
->process( $_POST )
->json();
```

config.php

```
<?php if (!defined('DATATABLES')) exit(); // Ensure being used in DataTables 
env.

/*
 * DB connection script for Editor
 * Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
 */

// Enable error reporting for debugging (remove for production)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

/*
 * Edit the following with your database connection options
 */
$sql_details = array(
"type" => "Mysql",
"user" => "root",
"pass" => "",
"host" => "localhost",
"port" => "",
"db"   => "myTable",
"dsn"  => "charset=utf8"
);
```

myTable.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Table</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/r-2.1.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/generator-base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editor.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/r-2.1.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/editor.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/table.Publications.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bootstrap">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>
            Table</span>
        </h1>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? How can I store data in the myTable.sql?

The error is:

```
DataTables warning: table id=myTable - An error occurred while connecting to the database 'myTable'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myTable'
```

Comment: Your question contains the statement **I set the config.php file with the name of the db it gives me an error.**.  What gives you the error? What error does it give you?  Please [edit] your question to show more specific information about your error.

Comment: This is the error: DataTables warning: table id=myTable - An error occurred while connecting to the database 'myTable'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myTable'

Comment: @O.Jones, Shouldnt table.myTable.sql create the db?

Comment: No, it creates the TABLE but not the database that should contain it.

Comment: @Salketer, so I should create the db in phpMyAdmin first?

Comment: yes, or whatever software you use to manage your database

Comment: @Salketer, It works, thank you!